# error al enviar un props desde laravel a vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Tengo el siguiente problema con el envió de un *props* a **Vue** desde **laravel 6.0**, el código en la vista blade:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <menuintranet :details="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"></menuintranet>
        <main id="page-content-wrapper" role="main" style="padding: 15px">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
```

El problema es que la vista no renderiza mostrando el siguiente error por consola

[image: Error consola]

He intentado de todo, pero nada, aunque creo que puede ser porque la cadena UUID la esta interpretando como variable y estas no pueden iniciar con valores numericos, creo yo.

como podria conseguirlo, porfa de su ayuda

saludos y buen dia

Comment: ¿Como esta declarado el prop en vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la id del usuario es un string así `984g43-34y34y-34y3e-33tgtr`, la parte de Laravel se ejecuta antes; entonces, al escribir la propiedad así

```
:details="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"`
```

Luego el compilador interpretará eso de la siguiente manera:

```
:details="877sd86-233fd25-32523fh5"
```

Y esperará una variable, que tiene el nombre `877sd86-233fd25-32523fh5`.

No compila pues los nombres de las variables no pueden comenzar con un número [SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Identifier_after_number).

Puedes evitarlo pasándole el valor de la variable a v-bind como texto, agregando comillas simples.

```
// Laravel lee
<menuintranet :details="'{{ Auth::user()->id }}'" ></menuintranet>
// Vue lee
<menuintranet :details="'984g43-34y34y-34y3e-33tgtr'" ></menuintranet>
```

O, simplemente puedes omitir los dos puntos v-bind y pasarlo como una propiedad estática:

```
// Laravel lee
<menuintranet details="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" ></menuintranet>
// Vue lee
<menuintranet details="984g43-34y34y-34y3e-33tgtr" ></menuintranet>
```

Un ejemplo sin la parte de Laravel:

```js
Vue.component('menuintranet', {
  props: ['details'],
  template: '<h1>{{ details  }}</h1>'
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <menuintranet :details="'984g43-34y34y-34y3e-33tgtr'"></menuintranet>
   <menuintranet details="984g43-34y34y-34y3e-33tgtr"></menuintranet>
</div>
```